# Check array equality with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've got a method inside the file test.ts:

```
public async listComponentsDiffer(lastTag: string, workDir: string): Promise<any[]>
```

This method return me a array like this :

```
[{ components: "toto", newVersion: "2", oldVersion: "1" }]
```

I'm trying to use Jest and I'm doing this for check this method:

```
test("correct array form", () => {
    // Given
    const lastag = "";
    const workDir = ".";

    // When
    const result = ComponentsService.listComponentsDiffer(lastag, workDir);

    // Then
    const expected = [{ components: "toto", newVersion: "2", oldVersion: "1" }];
    expect(result).toBe(expected);
});
```

But I've got thsi error :

```
TypeError: test_1.test.listComponentsDiffer is not a function Jest
```

How can I do my test ?

Comment: check if `listComponentsDiffer` method is static, if not you could create a new object of `ComponentsService` and call the method. By the signature, we see that you are getting back a promise so you need to call `.then` on `result` and inside the function you could call `expect`

Answer (score 9):

1. This method is an instance method, not a class static method. Need to be called from an instance of the class.
2. This method uses `async/await` syntax, you need to add `async/await` to your test case as well.
3. Instead of using `.toBe`, you should use `.toEqual`.

> Use .toEqual to compare recursively all properties of object instances (also known as "deep" equality)

E.g.

`test.ts`:

```js
export class ComponentsService {
  public async listComponentsDiffer(lastTag: string, workDir: string): Promise<any[]> {
    return [{ components: 'toto', newVersion: '2', oldVersion: '1' }];
  }
}
```

`test.test.ts`:

```js
import { ComponentsService } from './test';

describe('60667611', () => {
  test('correct array form', async () => {
    const lastag = '';
    const workDir = '.';
    const instance = new ComponentsService();

    const result = await instance.listComponentsDiffer(lastag, workDir);

    const expected = [{ components: 'toto', newVersion: '2', oldVersion: '1' }];
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/60667611/test.test.ts (7.968s)
  60667611
    ✓ correct array form (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.014s
```